# Difference between text mining and topic modeling

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, text-mining, topic-modeling

I am bit confused when people talk about text mining and topic modelling randomly in the discussions. Can anyone please explain the exact meaning of these two and their differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Text mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mining) is a broad topic.

[Topic modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) is one possible subtopic of text mining.

For further details, please see Wikipedia.